# Dynamic range that selects the latest non blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a 5 year average for all 12 months in Oct/Sept

Anyone knows a formula that defines a dynamic range that selects the latest 5 non blank cells (Horizontally)

Cells from 18/19 (J5:J16) onward are blank cells

Screenshot
[image]

Thanks

Comment: what are the "latest" cells?  Could you show an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I would like a formula to select E5:I5 since J5 is blank for now.
The formula should be capable of selecting F5:J5 when there is data in J5

Comment: `=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B5,0,COUNT(C5:L5)-5,1,5))`